# Creating a new column to link text from column C in line with column B to column A

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 3 columns in Excel, Column A and B have the same text Labels but they are out of order and some rows in column A have been merged with (So I can't just add a filter and make them alphabetical order). Column C contains names and is in the correct order to the labels of column B. I want to create a new column (D) that has the names attached to the same labels of B in the order of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I must check that I have understood you correctly. So, your data looks something like this:

```
TextLabel2,TextLabel1,Patricia
TextLabel1,TextLabel2,Sarah
TextLabel3,TextLabel3,Tony
```

And you want to add a fourth column that reads:

```
Sarah-TextLabel1
Patricia-TextLabel2
Tony-TextLabel3
```

Is that right? If so you need to put this formula in all relevant cells of column D:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$C,2,FALSE)&"-"&B1
=VLOOKUP(A2,$B:$C,2,FALSE)&"-"&B2
=VLOOKUP(A3,$B:$C,2,FALSE)&"-"&B3
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks that basically was what I needed, take out the last (&"-"&BX) and it was exactly what I wanted. Just curious, if there are no values the result will spit out N/A. How do I add in an IF statement that will make the N/A results report as text of my choice?

Comment: This is the way I've always done it although it appears a little cumbersome: `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A3,$B:$C,2,FALSE)),"Missing",VLOOKUP(A3,$B:$C,2,FALSE))`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using office 2007 and latter you can wrap your formula with iferror as

=iferror(your_formula,"")

If using office 2003 or lower then

If(iserror(your_formula),"",your_formula)
Thanks